# Add event to prevent timeout inside Inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a timeout function

```
var idleTimeOut = 60; // 1 minute

ResetIdleSecondsEvent = function () {
    // Reset counter for all listed event
    $(document).on("click mousemove keypress touchstart touchend touchcancel touchmove", function () {            
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    })      
}        
  function VerifyTimeOutInterval() {
    // Run every seconds to call function and check if current counter is more than
    // the preset time
    window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);
}    

 function CheckIdleTime() {        
    // Check timer only predefined timeout value is not 0, null or empty
    if (idleTimeOut != "") {
        // Increase counter for seconds
        _idleSecondsCounter++;

        // Check if current counter is more than the preset timeout period
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= idleTimeOut) {
            // Notify user that he/she has been automatically logged out
            navigator.notification.alert("You have been automatically logged out due " +
                "to inactivity. Please login again.", function () { }, "Logged Out", 'OK');

            // Navigate to login page
            self.navigateLogout();
        }
    }      
}
```

This works great in my application when user do nothing for 1 minutes, timeout message will appear and take user to login screen.

But when user open an external link using Inappbrowser and has activity, the idle seconds did not get reset, the timeout message appear and take user back to login. So how do I add the same code into Inapp browser?

As far as I know, the Inappbrowser only has the event loadstart, loadstop, loaderror and exit. I tried the following code to add event into Inappbrowser but no luck.

```
var inappBrowserObj = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
inappBrowserObj.addEventListener('loadstop', ResetIdleSecondsEvent());
inappBrowserObj.addEventListener('loadstop', VerifyTimeOutInterval());
```

Please tell me what is the correct way to handle timeout function inside Inappbrowser.

Thanks

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle or plunker

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be wrong while implementing the event handlers. Your callbacks are incorrectly passed and also you don't need to register handlers for same event twice (though you can but not required). Your code should be:

```
inappBrowserObj.addEventListener('loadstop', ResetIdleSecondsEvent);
```

Observe how I have passed the callback, your code will execute that function instead of passing it as a callback.

Make your other function calls within the `ResetIdleSecondsEvent` function.

I hope this helps.